# Need to count the number of documents in a particular directory using python - MapReduce

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapreduce, mrjob

Please find the below program that I'm using. It is compiling but not giving any output. Request to help with error.

```
import gzip
import warc
import os
from mrjob.job import MRJob


class DocumentCounter(MRJob):
    def mapper(self, _, line):
        entries = os.listdir("C://Users//HP//WARCDataset")
        for entry in entries:
            yield 1,1

    def reducer(self, key, values):

        yield key, sum(values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     DocumentCounter.run()
```

[image] The screenshot of the IDE and the output window. The result is not displayed even though the program runs to success.

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with your code, but do you really need a class to count number of documents? You can do it easily by: `b = len([x for x in os.listdir(folder) if x.endswith(file_extension)])`.

Comment: @pavel: Like you said, it is possible to do it with Python internals function, but she wants to use *MapReduce* algorithm, so she needs a class.

Comment: @NachiketDeo: Your code seems to be right. Can you show how your run the code from your Terminal ?

Comment: @codrelphi Thanks for the review. I'm running the code on local machine on Enthought- Canopy IDE by pressing 'Run' button. I'm not using any command to run the file. Please let me know if there's any command that can be used to run.

Comment: It is possible to run the script from your Terminal and to specify where the outputs should be located. You can check the documentation here https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides.html

Comment: @codrelphi. I have attached the screenshot of my IDE in the body of the question. The program runs but doesn't provide any output. Hence, I feel that something must be wrong in my code.Some minor mistake as I'm novice in Python MapReduce

Comment: @NachiketDeo Your output should be in one of the folders listing beside the line *job output is in* or *streaming final output from*. You can check those folders.

Comment: @codrelphi The output folders don't exist. They get removed at run time.I researched the issue and it seems that mrjob requires input from STDIN.

Comment: Try to check the *outputs folder*  by using your Terminal (*Command Line Interface*). Also, by checkng the *documentation*, you will know how to specify the *outputs folder* in your Terminal.

Comment: Your code doesn't work if multiple mappers are started. You'll be recounting things. Therefore, you're required to use one mapper, therefore not really taking full advantage of MapReduce parallelism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class DocumentCounter(MRJob):
   
    def mapper_raw(self,_,line):
        for fname in os.listdir(WARC_PATH):
            yield "total_documents",1

    def combiner(self, key, values):
    """
    Sums up count for each mapper.
    """
        yield key, sum(values)
                

    def reducer(self, key, values):
    ##TOTAL_DOUCMENTS = sum(values)
        NumberofDocuments = sum(values)     
        yield key, NumberofDocuments


       
    if __name__ == '__main__':
         DocumentCounter.run()
```

**The above code uses os.listdir function to iterate to all files at given path**

Comment: Is this a solution to your problem or is this supposed to be part of the question? Seems to me the latter

Comment: This is a solution to the problem. This code when given directory correct path provide answer to number of documents in that particular directory